# Oracle SQL group by query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have below data

```
Name   ID    Action      Action_Date
A123   234     ADD        21/05/2016
A123   234     DELETE     25/05/2016
A124   235     ADD        21/05/2016
A125   236     DELETE     25/05/2016
```

Now am trying to get below result

```
Name    ID   Date_Added     Dated_Deleted
A123    234     21/05/2016    25/05/2016
A124    235     21/05/2016     NULL
A125    236       NULL         25/05/2016
```

I know I need to group by Name and ID but not quite getting how to get the desired output. Please help

Comment: Search for `Conditional Aggregate`

Comment: And pick a DBMS instead of tagging all of them.

Answer (score 1):

When you are trying to flatten the data, it is called a PIVOT. If you are using Oracle, there is a keyword of that name that could be used, but I prefer the old method of conditionally aggregating (mentioned by @Prdp in a comment). The code will be very simple.

```
SELECT t.name
      ,t.id
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN t.action = 'ADD' THEN t.action_date END) AS date_added
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN t.action = 'DELETE' THEN t.action_date END) AS date_deleted
  FROM your_table t
 GROUP BY t.name
         ,t.id;
```